# Compression in KDB using gzip

Tags: kdb

I am trying to compress data while storing on disk using KDB. I came through this tutorial for Saving in-memory data directly to compressed format on disk :

http://www.firstderivatives.com/downloads/q_for_gods_Oct_2013.pdf

**(`:targetFile;logicalBlockSize;compressionAlgorithm;compressionLevel)
set table**

logicalBlockSize is a power of 2 between 12 and 20 (pageSize or allocation granularity to 1MB -pageSize for AMD64 is 4kB, sparc is 8kB. Windows seems to have a default allocation granularityof 64kB). Note that this argument affects both compression speed and compression ratio (larger
blocks can be slower and better compressed)

 compressionAlgorithm is one of the following, 0 - none, 1 - kdb+ ipc, 2 - gzip

 compressionLevel is between 0 and 9 (valid only for gzip, use 0 for other algorithms)

Please suggest which algorithm will be the best to go with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definitive "best", it depends on various factors (which are discussed [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/FileCompression)). I generally use the built-in kdb compression with settings (17;1;0)